# What chart used in google analytics for "Views by Page title and screen class"?

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, react-google-charts

I am looking for a chart name which is used in Google Analytics dashboard (see the snapshots)

I am using `react-google-charts` on my web app but can't found the same type of chart in it.

[image]

[image: on hovering the row]

Comment: That doesn't look like a chart, just a table.

Comment: @underscore_d thanks for the reply, I'll create a table for this problem

Answer (score 2):

The chart that you're looking for will only be available to you once you upgrade to Google Analytics 4.

[image: Screenshot from Google Analytics]

Comment: I'm on GA 4 and the thing is bare empty. Suspect there's more to it than that